# Best Architecture for offloading high usage Key in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We have been using Kafka for various use cases and have solved various problems. But the one problem which we are frequently facing is messages with any one key will be suddenly produced more or it will take some secs of execution so that the messages for the other keys in the queue are processed in delay.

We have implemented various ways to find those keys and offloaded it to a separate queue where we will be having a topic pool. But the topics in the pool goes on increasing and we find that we are not using the topic resource in an efficient manner.

If we are having 100 such keys, then we need to create 100 such topics and this not seems to be an optimised solution.

Whether in these type of cases, we should store the data in the DB where the particular key's data resides and we need to implement our own Queue based on the data in the table or there is some other mechanisms in which we can solve this problem ?

This problem is only for the keys having high data rate and high processing time (with 3 to 5s). Can anyone suggest what will be the better architecture for these type of cases?

Comment: Why create more topics rather than add more partitions for those keys? That's your only other option as far as Kafka configurations go

Comment: We analysed increasing the partition cases also. For RoundRobin case, if for the same key more number of messages are produced within a minute, then all the partitions are occupied by the same key. So there also we faced the same problem.

Comment: Equal keys should all go to the same partition, not all partitions unless you're manually setting that information when you produce the records